# Google Map: Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am trying to add some attributes to my manifest to initialize my google map but I am getting this error:

> Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix

How can I fix it?

**Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        map:cameraTargetLat = "63.868913" 
        map:cameraTargetLng= "14.665491"
        map:cameraZoom="15"/>
```

Comment: map:cameraTargetLat what is map stand for ?? that's the error

Comment: I am working this video tutorial and it stand there https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qj3gWK-TaTk&index=15&list=PLVTeA3WccG_6a3NeZYPWpjGgaljA_zqle minute 2:45 ??

Comment: but he added xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" at 0:53

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` in xml such that:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          tools:context=".MapsActivity"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
          map:cameraTargetLat="63.868913"
          map:cameraTargetLng="14.665491"
          map:cameraZoom="15"/>
```